# Как сделать кнопки в Telegram bot на Python горизонтально

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
def start(message):
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Библиотека', callback_data='bibl'))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Анализ данных', callback_data='data'))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='списки', callback_data='list'))
```

Есть кнопки, но они в столбик. Как сделать чтобы они были в горизонтальном положении? Например, чтобы кнопки `библиотека` и `анализ данных` были горизонтально, а кнопка `списки` была под ними.

`row_widht=2`и `3` не помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я помню, там надо просто сгруппировать кнопки вложенными списками прежде чем передавать их в `InlineKeyboardMarkup`.

Т.е. что-то типа такого:

```
b1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Библиотека', callback_data='bibl')
b2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Анализ данных', callback_data='data')
b3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='списки', callback_data='list')
row1 = [ b1, b2 ]
row2 = [ b3 ]
buttons = [ row1, row2 ]
markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло